# ssl-based wcf service does not work in azure emulator

Tags: wcf, ssl, azure, iis-express

If i put the web role to run in IIS, the service goes as expected.
however, it does not work in azure emulator. The error page shows "500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed."

I doubt it is caused by below setting:

```
<system.webServer>
        <security>
           <access sslFlags="Ssl, SslNegotiateCert, SslRequireCert" />
        </security>
 </system.webServer>
```

But i have set up a startup task as in azure  below:

```
<WebRole name="WCFServiceWebRole" vmsize="ExtraSmall">
    <Startup>
      <Task commandLine="startup\unlockSession.cmd" executionContext="elevated" />
    </Startup>
</WebRole>
```

And its content is:

> %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd unlock config /section:system.webServer/security/access

Anyone has encountered the same issue? Help!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It is most likely not your startup script that's causing problems - usually problems there cause the role to not even start. But there's not enough information here to tell what the problem actually is. Look at your event logs, set breakpoints in the WebRole.cs and/or Global.asax application error handler, and generally try to collect more information. You might also check for errors in your web.config - that's a common cause of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled SSL endpoint in servicedefinition file as below

```
<Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="https" port="443" certificate="SSLcertificate" />
    </Endpoints> <Certificates>
      <Certificate name="SSLcertificate" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
    </Certificates>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is because your emulator is using IIS Express rather than full IIS. In the case `appcmd` would have another path: `C:\Program Files\IIS Express\appcmd.exe`.

But for more correct and complete solution see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18541845/393672).